# Получить id добавленной записи

Tags: android, android-room

Записываю данные о категории в БД следующим образом. Как затем получить id добавленной записи?

```
MyBookDB db = AppDatabase.getInstance().getMyBookDB();
CategoryDao categoryDao = db.categoryDao();

Completable.fromAction(() -> categoryDao.insertCategory(category))
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(new CompletableObserver() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                // just like with a Single
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {
                // action was completed successfully

            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                // something went wrong
            }
        });
```

Сам интерфейс CategoryDao

```
@Dao
public interface CategoryDao {

    @Insert
    long insertCategory(Category category);

}
```

Comment: Не очень ясен вопрос. У вас есть метод insertCategory - он как раз и возвращает ID записи.

Comment: Вместо `Completable` попробуйте использовать `Single` или `Maybe`

Comment: Ниже ответ написал свой как получилось. Спасибо. Через Single или Maybe можете дать ссылку на пример как это делается? В курсе startandroid примера конкретного нет.

Answer (score 0):

В categoryID записываем ID

```
MyBookDB db = AppDatabase.getInstance().getMyBookDB();
CategoryDao categoryDao = db.categoryDao();

Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<Object>() {
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception {
        return categoryDao.insertCategory(category);
    }
}).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Consumer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public void accept(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
        categoryID = (long) o;

    }
});
```